# PySNMP can not send traps with AES encryption on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, pysnmp

I use `pysnmp` Python lib for sending traps and `snmptrap` command line tool for receiving, but  clients can not parse when I use AES encryption.

The interesting thing, if I use DES or turn off encryption, then it works. And if I send AES encrypted traps with command line tools, then it works too

Here is the version of used libs:

```
dpkg -l | grep pysnmp
ii  python-pysnmp-common                4.1.9a-2ubuntu1               Python SNMP library for agents and managers (version selection module)
ii  python-pysnmp4                      4.1.9a-2ubuntu1               Python SNMP library for agents and managers (unstable branch)
```

Comment: Those versions are really old. I'd advise using the most recent *development* versions of pysnmp & pyasn1 whenever possible. See http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/changes.html for more information on the changes and fixes.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof: Have you any PPA repo for continuous upgrade on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

### I have found a mailing thread about this problem

http://sourceforge.net/p/pysnmp/mailman/message/27820538/

> Your test case works for me with pysnmp release 4.1.16a. According to
> the  pysnmp/CHANGES file, many AES-related fixes have been made at
> 4.1.14a.
>
> Therefore please upgrade to the latest pysnmp release (4.1.16a) and
> try  again.
>
> -ilya

### Solution

Do upgrade `python-pysnmp4` package to **4.1.16a+** version. The *Ubuntu Precise* does not contain fixed versions, so you have two choice:

- Upgrade lib with `pip` / `easy_install` tool

  For more info: http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/download.html
- Install DEB from *Ubuntu Raring+* releases, *e.g: `python-pysnmp4=4.2.2-1`*

  For more info: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python-pysnmp4

**FYI:** The dependency of `python-pysnmp4` DEB is wrong in Ubuntu, so have to update `python-pyasn1` package too! *e.g: `python-pyasn1=0.1.4-0ubuntu1`*

---

### Update

Here is the changelog for tracking changes / checking bugfixes: http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/changes.html

*Thank you ilya!*